# What if pendingintent call getService() to start a living background service multiple times

Tags: android

What if PendingIntent call getService() to start a background service (which is live) multiple times?
My guess is that the background service will still be there except onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) will be called multiple times, Correct?

In my case I am trying to call requestActivityUpdates() to detect user's activity (moving, still,...). When there are detected activities (callback function called), the example here (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition) uses the pendingintent to call intentservice to extract the results of those detected activities then broadcast it.
Since I need to process these detected activities in a background service, I am thinking can I use the pendingintent to start my background service directly instead of calling a intentservice and broadcast it to my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that the background service will still be there except onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) will be called multiple times, Correct?

If the service is still running, `onStartCommand()` will be called on the running instance.